# How can I load the images url to carousal getting from some api on document load using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am making a carousal and I want to load the images which I am getting from the API and I am trying to do this with the help of jQuery.

My html is this

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
            <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>Second Slide</h3>
            <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My API response

```
    "item": {

        "images": [
            "https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg",
            "https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/calm-reflective-water-background_bjnehswwh__F0000.png"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f3628d3200006f15a625e0", function( data ) {
        var i = data.item.images.length;

    var $img = $('<img src="http://www.silverstar-academy.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/03-14-12N00184967.jpg" />').on('load', function(){
                var s=data.item.images[j];
                $(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url('+$img+')>' +
                    '<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">' +
                    '<h3 style="color: #1c7430">first</h3>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>');
            console.log(data.item.images[j]);

        });


});
```

Comment: What were you not able to do so far ? You should show code of what you tried to do

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "http://www.mocky.io/v2/59f3628d3200006f15a625e0", function( data ) {
        var i = data.item.images.length;

        var $img = $('<img src="http://www.silverstar-academy.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/03-14-12N00184967.jpg" />').on('load', function(){
            var s=data.item.images[j];
            $(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url('+$img+')>' +
                '<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"><h3 style="color: #1c7430">first</h3></div></div>');
        });
   });